# Несколько значений переменной JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Если пользователь вводит в текстовую форму допустим: "open google"
Так вот и мы проверяем через if если он это ввел тогда откроем ему гугл `window.open( 'http://google.com');` так вот но как сделать несколько вариаций 
по типу: "open", "show me", "turn on" + google и так далее...

Так вот что бы не писать if к каждому случаю как лучше всего проверять если в предложении которое написал пользователь одно из Тех слов в начале, а после него идет слово google и только тогда выполнять код? Что если человек введет open google, или show me google, или turn on google все равно выполниться одна функция!

Comment: регулярные выражения.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="in"> <input type="button" id="btn" value="go">
```

---

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = function() {
    var text = document.getElementById('in').value.trim();

    if (text.match(/^(open|show\sme|turn\son)\sgoogle$/) != null) {
        alert('open google!');
    }
};
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n99pxgq8/)